# dynamic image src playframework

Tags: playframework-1.x

i want to show dynamic image in my view that corresponds to the users profile picture.

my controller has following:

```
render(..,userImage);
```

in my view i do this

```
<img src="${'../public/images/'+userImage}" alt="logo" id="logo" class="center"/>
```

on my local machine everything works as i am using `localhost:9005`. when i deploy to my test machine, the url i use is `http://testserver/AdminConsole` and the view shows a broken image as it is looking for the image in `http://testserver/public/images/userJohn1234.jpg`

Is this not permitted with playframework 1.2.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply remove dots

```
<img src="/public/images/${userImage}" alt="logo" id="logo" class="center"/>
```